# JavaScript Array value changing issue

Tags: javascript

**Question:** Write a function called make_album() that builds a Object describing a music album. The function should take in an artist name and an album title, and it should return a Object containing these two pieces of information. Use the function to make three dictionaries representing different albums. Print each return value to show that Objects are storing the album information correctly. Add an optional parameter to make_album() that allows you to store the number of tracks on an album. If the calling line includes a value for the number of tracks, add that value to the album’s Object. Make at least one new function call that includes the number of tracks on an album.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Assignment-1</title>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
  <script>
    
    const magicians=['Joker','Pinkro','Neuro'];

    function show_magicians(magicians){
       
        console.log(`${magicians}`);
    
    }
    function make_great(magicians){
        great_magicians=[];
        while(magicians){

            let magician=magicians.pop();
            great_magician=magician+' the Great';
            great_magicians.append(great_magician);
        }

        for(great_magician of great_magicians){
            magicians.append(great_magician);
        }
    }
    show_magicians(magicians);
    make_great(magicians);
    </script>
</html>
```

*I'm getting this error: Uncaught TypeError: great_magicians.append is not a function
at make_great (42.html:64:29)
at 42.html:72:5*

Comment: There is no `Array.append` method.  See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push

Comment: What does your code have to do with albums like the task asks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe javascript uses `Array.push` to add items to arrays not `Array.append`.